# f.readlines() does not include the line that has been f.readline()

Tags: python, file

I thought I'd understood the definition of `f.readline()` until I stumbled upon the following problem

let test.txt be the following text file

```
I'm the first line
Second 
Third
```

Then

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.readline())
    print(f.readlines())
```

The code outputs:

```
I'm the first line

['second \n', 'third']
```

Why is `f.readlines()` not containing the first line? Has `f.readline()` perhaps moved the pointer to the next line?

Could someone please explain to me what does `f.readline()` do exactly and how can I avoid this behaviour? (except maybe store the line and then add the line back which is kind of inefficient)

Comment: “Has the f.readline() perhaps moved the pointer to the next line?”  Essentially, yes.  You can use `f.seek(0)` to ‘reset’ the cursor to the start of file.  Where the 0 is the offset, in bytes.

Comment: If it didn't advance the file pointer, the only thing it could ever return is the first line, in which case it's not very useful (and would probably be named `read_first_line` instead of `readline`).

Comment: nit: The code does not "return" the text as describe in the comment.  It "outputs" that text.  It's a seemingly minor point that often causes a great deal of confusion.  Side effects (like output) and return values are very different things.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry didn't notice it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: What's inefficient about keeping data in memory and reusing it? That's certainly much _more_ efficient than rereading from disk, which involves context switching into kernel space to deliver the syscalls requesting the seek.

Answer (score 0):

To get the behavior you want you will need to manipulate the file pointer between f.readline() and f.readlines():

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    print(f.readline())
    f.seek(0)
    print(f.readlines())
```

- The f.readline() will read test.txt up to the first newline (i.e., "I'm the first line\n"), leaving the file pointer ready to read from that point on (i.e., ready to read just before "Second").
- The f.seek(0) will move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file (i.e., ready to read just before "I'm").  Without this, f.readlines() would just continue reading from where f.readline() left off.
- Finally, f.readlines() will read the file from the file pointer (currently at the beginning of the file) and, using any newlines it finds, break what it reads into a list of strings.